# Compare text from two files and do something if they are diffrent

Tags: batch-file, version-control, diff, difference

So I need to compare two text files and if there is a difference in content in one of them then tell the batch file to `GOTO Diffrence` I know that the FC command can check diffrences but can I use it to make it goto a diffrent place

so I run
`fc %cd%\ActiveVer.txt %cd%\currentver.txt`

ActiveVer.txt says:
`0.5.6`

and currentver.txt says:
`0.5.7`
fc tells me the difference.

But I'm trying to see and make it run `GOTO out-of-date` if there is a difference and do `echo You are up to date!` if there is none.

- **Should I run another command to do this or is there something that allows me to do that with fc?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commands return an error code upon completion. By convention, zero equates to success, and non-zero equates to failure (this is a general rule - there are exceptions). So most of this answer can be applied to any command, as long as you know how to interpret the returned error code.

The FC command returns 0 if the files match, and 1 it there is at least one difference. You don't need to see the output of the command (the differences), so you can redirect stdout to nul.

One option is to use IF ERRORLEVEL N, which evaluates to true if the returned error code is >= N.

```
fc ActiveVer.txt CurrentVer.txt >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto outOfDate
echo you are Up-To-Date
exit /b

:outOfDate
echo you are Out-Of-Date
exit /b
```

*Note that `%cd%\file` and `file` are equivalent - the `%cd%` is not needed.*

Another option is to check for a specific value by using the dynamic %ERRORLEVEL% "variable".

```
fc ActiveVer.txt CurrentVer.txt >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 goto outOfDate
echo you are Up-To-Date
exit /b

:outOfDate
echo you are Out-Of-Date
exit /b
```

But I almost never use either syntax above. Instead I use the conditional command concatenation operators `&&` and `||`. Commands after `&&` only execute if the prior command returned zero, and commands after `||` execute if the command returned non-zero. Note that commands after `&&` might fail, which could cause the `||` commands to fire, even if the original command succeeded. For this reason, it is a good idea to end your `&&` commands with a command that is guaranteed to succeed. A good choice is `(call )`, which does nothing other than return 0 (success).

```
someCommand && (
  REM Success commands go here
  REM Make sure the last commmand in this block returns 0
  (call )
) || (
  REM Error commands go here
)
```

You simply want to GOTO if FC "fails" (finds a difference), so you only need the `||`.

```
fc ActiveVer.txt CurrentVer.txt >nul || goto outOfDate
echo You are Up-To-Date
exit /b

:outOfDate
echo You are Out-Of-Date
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I almost forgot about errorlevel. From most things I've done I have always stayed away from using ERRORLEVEL knowing it can be sometimes dangerous. 

Also I am happy that you showed another way of getting this done.